# Firebase CLI: No project is currently active

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm following this Firebase intro tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/

I follow the instructions and when I get to [step 3](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#3), I run `firebase use --add` and I get the following:

```
# firebase use --add

> web-start@1.0.0 firebase ~/repos/friendlychat/web-start
> firebase "use"

No project is currently active.

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.
```

But if I run `firebase list` I see this:

```
┌──────────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Name         │ Project ID / Instance │ Permissions │
├──────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ FriendlyChat │ friendlychat-x3sd0    │ Owner       │
└──────────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

So I am clearly logged in correctly as I can list my projects and have some sort of access to them on the CLI. But does the error mean it's not active? How do I activate it? There is nothing in the tutorial about this.

What am I missing here? Seems like it's something obvious that I'm just not seeing.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue and fixed it by running `firebase init` again.
The file that was missing was the `.firebaserc`.

The content of this file

```
{
   "projects": {
     "default": "yourid"
   }
}
```

hope that helps,
Muki

Comment: rerunning `firebase init` and selecting appropriate values helped, looks like I did not provide some information when doing it first time

Comment: I had to remove `.firebaserc` from `.gitignore`

Answer (score 9):

you could run your required command (i.e `firebase deploy`, or any firebase command you're trying to use and gtting this error) with "project flag", like this:

```
firebase deploy --project my-project-id
```

and you will be good to go

Comment: Event though i have a `.firebaserc` in my project I still need to run with the `--project my-proj-id` flag.

Answer (score 2):

type `firebase use default` before deploying to use the default project in `.firebaserc`

Answer (score 1):

To active a Firebase project, you can run command `firebase use <project-id>`, in your case it would be `firebase use friendlychat-x3sd0`.